# Integral evaluation - Gamma distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, probability-distributions

I have a sequence of independent random variables which are $\chi^2(1)$ distributed, $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$, $X_i\sim\chi^2(1)$. If I consider the sum
$\frac{t}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}$ this should be $\sim\text{Gamma}(\alpha=n/2,\theta=2/n)$, for a $t>0$.

I want to show that $\mathbb{P}[\text{Gamma}(\alpha=n/2,\theta=2/n)\geq n\epsilon]$ is not summable over $n$.

For this I have to compute the following integral
$$\gamma(n/2,\epsilon n^2/2)=\int_0^{\epsilon n^2/2}{t^{n/2-1}e^{-t}dt}$$ and find an appropriate bound.

Can someone tell me if I am right and maybe give advice for this computation?
Thanks

Comment: I think some normalization constant is missing, since $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^{n/2-1}e^{-t}\,dt = (n/2-1)!.$$

Comment: And anyway, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k$ converges to a normal distribution by the CLT.

Comment: Yes but I really need the integral evaluated for fixed n in order to check if it is summable or not. I see your argument above but as I wrote above I do not see where the missing normalization term could come from

Comment: $t^{n/2-1}e^{-t}$ is not a probability density function over $\mathbb{R}^+$ without the right normalization constant.

Comment: Yes you are right $\frac{1}{\Gamma(n/2)}$ is missing as factor in the integral. But it is really not my point here.